How to inject some but not all parameters
In my team's codebase I see classes that either have all parameters injected (and no constructor arguments) or have nothing injected. However, I'm wondering how to have a class with some injected and some not? For example:
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class HTTPWrapper {
    private final HttpClient httpClient;
    private final DatabaseClient databaseClient;
    private String rootUrl;
    private String defaultHeaders;
    public HTTPWrapper( [what to put here?] ) {
        ... [and here?]
    }
}

If it's not clear, I want the String stuff to be passed in.
I've looked at this: Inject only certain params in constructor, but it is not about Java; one of the comments discusses Java, but it was too vague for me to understand.

This is specifically covered in the Dagger documentation on assisted injection.

Assisted injection is a dependency injection (DI) pattern that is used to construct an object where some parameters may be provided by the DI framework and others must be passed in at creation time (a.k.a “assisted”) by the user.

